# Button disappears when increasing its height

Tags: android, android-layout

I try to create square buttons. When increasing the button's height, it disappears. However, when increasing it's width, everything works fine. What's going on there?

```
private void adjustButtons() {
        final Button trainerButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bu_vocabulary_start_trainer);

        trainerButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = shareButton.getLayoutParams();
//              params.width++; // works fine
                params.height++; // button disappears
//              params.height = params.width; // what I acutually want to do
                shareButton.setLayoutParams(params);
            }
        });

    }
```

The **xml file**

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bu_vocabulary_start_trainer"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/vocabulary_trainer" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bu_vocabulary_start_administration"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/vocabulary_administration" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,

```
private void adjustButtons() {
        final Button trainerButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bu_vocabulary_start_trainer);

        trainerButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = shareButton.getLayoutParams();
//              params.width++; // works fine
                params.height++; // button disappears
//              params.height = params.width; // what I acutually want to do
                shareButton.setLayoutParams(params);
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: This worked for me. However, when increasing the height in a loop, the buttons still disappear.

Answer (score 0):

you should use dp number for your height and weight.

height++ doesn't work for `wrap_content`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `WRAP_CONTENT` is [just an integer value, which maps to -2](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html#WRAP_CONTENT). Increasing it would change it to -1, which is `MATCH_PARENT`.

You see the situation now? Your LinearLayout has height `WRAP_CONTENT`. This means "make its height as large as need be to contain its children". If the children are set to `MATCH_PARENT`, that would mean "make them as large as their parent". This situation is resolved by making both parent and children 0 pixels high. Hence, they "disappear".

What you could do, though, is something like:

```
params.height = shareButton.getHeight() + 1;
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know that WRAP_CONTENT and MATCH_PARENT are just integer values.

Answer (score 0):

This line might help you:

```
button.setLayoutParams (new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, yourheight++);
```